# Porquê estou recebendo undefined no retorno desta função?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Estou criando um agente no Dialogflow e utilizando Airtable como BD.

Está tudo funcionando bem, estou conseguindo acessar o BD e trazer os resultados.

Mas não consigo "jogar o resultado pra fora" da função e acessá-la no final para poder imprimir.

Segue código:

```
function showSinglePrice(agent) {
    var finalPrice;
    var arraySinglePrice = null;

    const item = agent.context.get("item"),
      place = item.parameters.place,
      size = item.parameters.size,
      type = item.parameters.type;

    base(tablePizzas)
      .select({
        maxRecords: 10, //
        view: viewName,
        filterByFormula: `AND({type} = "${type}",{size} = "${size}",{place} = "${place}")` 
      })
      .firstPage(function(error, records) {
        if (error) {
          response.send({ error: error });
        } else {
          arraySinglePrice = records.map(record => {
            return {
              price: record.get("price")
            };
          });

          console.log(arraySinglePrice); //isso funfa

          var finalPrice = arraySinglePrice[0].price; //isso tb

          return finalPrice;
        }
      });   
   
    agent.add(`Valor deveria vir aqui: ${finalPrice}`); //não chega aqui

  }
```

Sempre dá *undefined*.

Já tentei várias coisas, mas estou travado.

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja porque você definiu a variável `finalPrice` 2 vezes. Uma vez logo no começo, e uma segunda vez antes do return. No caso da segunda vez você deveria fazer sem o `var`, apenas atribuindo o valor à variável: `finalPrice = arraySinglePrice[0].price;`.

Não sei se é isso, continue nos atualizando.

Comment: sua observação está correta. obrigado por apontar. corrigido agora.

Mesmo assim o problema persiste. 

O método que estou utilizando .select().firstpage() vem de uma biblioteca chamada airtable.js|

Este método retorna uma promise. 

Então sei na teoria que o JS está "avançando", tentando imprimir no fim antes do término do método.

Mas não sei fazer o código PARAR, esperar o término da chamada antes de avançar para a variável final.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você da o `return finalPrice;` ele sai da função não executando o `agent.add(Valor deveria vir aqui: ${finalPrice});`, tenta adicionar o `agent.add()` antes do `return`